# Derivative of the off-diagonal $L_1$ matrix norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

We define the off-diagonal $L_1$ norm of a matrix as follows: for any $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$, $$\|A\|_1^{\text{off}} = \sum_{i\ne j}|a_{ij}|.$$
So what is $$\frac{\partial \|A\|_1^{\text{off}}}{\partial A}\;?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The question changed after I answered. See comment below.)

I am not sure I would call this a norm, so let me write $\phi(A) = \sum_{i \neq j} [A]_{ij}$. It is easy to see that $\phi$ is linear, hence $D\phi(A)(\Delta) = \phi(\Delta) = \sum_{i \neq j} [\Delta]_{ij}$.

If you want a 'matrix' representation, let $e = (1,1,...,1)^T$ and define $\Gamma = e e^T - I$. Then $D\phi(A)(\Delta) = \operatorname{tr} (\Gamma^T \Delta)$ ($\Gamma$ is symmetric, so the transpose is irrelevant, I added it to make the connection with the inner product induced by the Frobenius norm).

Answer to updated question:

This is still not a norm, of course, but now we have $\nu(A) = \sum_{i \neq j} |[A]_{ij}|$. It should be clear that $\nu$ is differentiable iff $[A]_{ij} \neq 0$ for all $i \neq j$, and in this case we have $D \nu(A)(\Delta) = \sum_{i \neq j} \operatorname{sgn} [A]_{ij} [\Delta]_{ij}$. To obtain a 'matrix' representation, let $\Gamma$ be defined as $[\Gamma]_{ij} = \begin{cases} \operatorname{sgn} [A]_{ij} & i \neq j \\ 0 & i =j\end{cases}$, and then we have $D \nu(A)(\Delta) = \operatorname{tr} (\Gamma^T \Delta)$.

Comment: Do you mean that if at least one of the off-diagonal entries is zero then $\nu(A)$ is not differentiable?

Comment: And what is the expression of that derivative?

Comment: Yes, because that component then behaves like $x \mapsto |x|$ around $x=0$.

Comment: Ah ok you have just updated your answer. And what do you mean by $D\nu (A)(\Delta)$ is it simply $\frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A}$?

Comment: Not exactly; $D \nu(A)(\Delta) = \frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A} \Delta$. It is the partial 'applied' to the 'perturbation' $\Delta$. (It makes it easier to express the derivative.)

Comment: So if $\nu (A)$ is differentiable then $\frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A}=\mathrm{trace}(\Gamma^T)$?

Comment: I'm assuming here the perturbation $\Delta=I_n$.

Comment: No to both questions. $\frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A}$ doesn't have a nice expression as a single number. $\frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A}$ takes a matrix and returns a number. The behavior of the differential applied to some perturbation $\Delta$ is gives by $\operatorname{tr} (\Gamma^T \Delta)$. $\Delta$ is not necessarily $I$, it is any perturbation of the matrix $A$ (which is itself a matrix).

Comment: Perhaps this will help: $\frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial \nu (A)}{\partial A}(E_{ij}) = [\Gamma]_{ij} $, where $E_{ij}$ is a matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j$ position and zeroes everywhere else.

Comment: Okay thanks now I understand a particular choice of $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\t#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\s#1{\operatorname{sign}\LR{#1}}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Use the element-wise `sign()` function to define the matrix
$\,S = \s{X}.\;$

The gradient and differential of the Manhattan norm can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\g{\|X\|_1}{X} &= S \quad\iff\quad d\|X\|_1 = S:dX \\
}$$
Suppose that $X$ itself is defined in terms of another matrix $A$
$$\eqalign{
F &= (J-I), \qquad 
X &= F\odot A, \qquad
S &= \s{F\odot A} \\
}$$
where $J$ is the *all-ones* matrix, $I$ is the identity, and $(\odot)$ is the Hadamard product.

$\big($ Note that $X$ is composed of the off-diagonal elements of $A\,\big)$

Substituting into the known differential yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
&\quad d\|X\|_1 = S:dX = S:(F\odot dA) = (F\odot S):dA \\
&\boxed{\;\g{\|X\|_1}{A} = F\odot S\;}
\\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \t{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
and which commutes with the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
  &= (A\odot B):C \\\\
}$$

---

**NB**: The gradient above is not defined for any element of $X$ equal to zero, because the `sign()` function itself is discontinuous at zero.