# Second order derivative of off-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, partial-derivative, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A\in S_{++}^n$, so how to prove the convexity of of summation of abosolute values of this matrix? Do we need to take the second derivative ? Namely,
$$\|A\|_1^{\text{off}} = \sum_{i\ne j}|a_{ij}|.$$

So what is $$\frac{\partial^2 \|A\|_1^{\text{off}}}{\partial A^2}$$

Comment: What is $S_{++}^n$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/313704/9464

Comment: @Jack Thanks for your reply. $S_{++}^n$ means the positive definite symmetric matrix. I've read that thread but still have no idea how to prove the convexity of this matrix :P

Comment: The sum of convex functions is convex, and the absolute value function is convex. That's pretty much all you need.